# How to use 'mail' gem in rails 2.3.14 application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, actionmailer

I have a rails application running on rails 2.3.14.
I want to upgrade this application to rails 3. But before I do that, I wish to replace TMail gem (default in rails 2.3.x) to Mail gem (default for rails 3.x.x).

what all configuration changes do I need to do?